# How to get oauth2_proxy running in kubernetes under one domain to redirect back to original domain that required authentication?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, oauth-2.0, nginx-ingress

I've been setting up a kubernetes cluster and want to protect the dashboard (running at `kube.example.com`) behind the `bitly/oauth2_proxy` (running at `example.com/oauth2` on image `a5huynh/oauth2_proxy:latest`) as I want to re-use the OAuth proxy for other services I will be running. Authentication is working perfectly but after a user logs in, i.e. the callback returns, they are sent to `example.com` where instead they should be sent to the original host `kube.example.com` that initiated the flow. How can I do this? (I am using the nginx-ingress-controller).

Annotation on OAuth2 Proxy:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx",
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true",
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true",
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
```

Annotation on Dashboard:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx",
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://example.com/oauth2/start",
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://example.com/oauth2/auth",
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS",
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true",
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true",
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true",
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
```

I expect to be redirected to the original host `kube.example.com` after OAuth flow is complete but am being sent back to the OAuth2 host `example.com`

Comment: As far as I understood from their documentation oauth2_proxy should sit on the same domain as dashboard because what it does is effectively proxying requests to single upstream. I am not sure if it is capable of serving multiple upstreams.



Btw, we use Kong for that and it works pretty well with multiple upstreams and provides Google authentication to them.

Comment: Thanks for the response, apparently it is possible somehow (https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy/issues/12), I just have to figure out how to convert the nginx config into nginx ingress config... Kong could do it but then that becomes another application I have to manage.

Comment: From the link you gave it seems to be a hard work to optimize config for Nginx Ingress. At the same time Kong can serve you both as Nginx and oauth2_proxy, so it is more effective and makes configuration even simpler, that's my opinion.

Comment: I would agree with you that Kong would be simple, after some searching I did find a good solution and will post this as the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After searching for a bit I came across a [blog post](https://www.callumpember.com/Kubernetes-A-Single-OAuth2-Proxy-For-Multiple-Ingresses/) about performing this in a super simple manor. Unfortunately I found the provided [yaml](https://www.callumpember.com/assets/attachments/github-oauth2/full-deployment.yml.txt) did not quite work correctly as the oauth2_proxy was never being hit due to nginx intercepting all requests (I am not sure if mine was not working due to me wanting the oauth-proxy url to be `example.com/oauth2` rather than `oauth2.example.com`). To fix this I added back the oauth2-proxy path to the Ingress for the proxy i.e.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: oauth2-proxy
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
          - backend:
              serviceName: oauth2-proxy
              servicePort: 4180
            path: /oauth2
```

and made sure that the service was also still exposed i.e.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
    - name: http-proxy
      port: 4180
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
```

Then to protect services behind the oauth proxy I just need to place the following in the Ingress annotations:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://example.com/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://example.com/oauth2/start?rd=/redirect/$http_host$request_uri"
```